# Incomplete documentation for FreeBSD ipfw

Tags: freebsd, firewall, documentation, ipfw

When I see the [official documentation of ipfw](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/firewalls-ipfw.html) or [the man pages](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?ipfw(8)) it seems that it is sometimes incomplete. Specifically, there are a lot of options like,

```
firewall_myservices
firewall_allowservices
```

etc., which can be found in many [online guides](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/recommended-steps-for-new-freebsd-10-1-servers) but **not** in the docs. They're even discussed in the [lists](https://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-questions/2016-July/272455.html).

So I would like to understand if these are unofficial or undocumented options, and if they might be removed at some point in the future since they're not formally documented. More importantly, is there a single comprehensive documentation source for ipfw, short of grokking the source code?

Comment: Maybe you should open a bug report too (https://bugs.freebsd.org/bugzilla/).

Comment: Yes, that might actually be a good idea in this case. Just did it  https://bugs.freebsd.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=229363

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it seems that the options which are left out in the official docs are actually easily found in `/etc/rc.firewall`, which also happens to have the relevant explanations in the comments.

Comment: Then for better results add a patch to your bug report that copies that information into the rc.firewall manual.

Comment: Haven't looked but man pages will often refer you to the comments in the conf files for more information. General practice on FreeBSD is to look in the conf files also.

Comment: I think there is no need to start a big fuss on variables in /etc/rc.firewall. Actually, some of oldschool guys usually wipe its contents and write rules by hand ignoring the template.